# This question is related to proportions in R programing

Tags: r

[image]

I was asked to write code to find the proportions of females and males in each year of a data set but the code turned out to be wrong.

```
freq.table = table(olympicData$Sex, olympicData$Year)
Total = rowSums(freq.table)
Freq = freq.table/Total`
```

Comment: Please show some of your data

Comment: If you are new in SO, you should have a look to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#:~:text=%20How%20to%20create%20a%20Minimal%2C%20Reproducible%20Example,tell%20other%20readers%20what%20the%20expected...%20More%20

Comment: I added a picture of the summary of the data.

Comment: Pictures are useless. Some (small amount) of ACTUAL data.

Comment: Hi, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to help you make reproducible example. You can start with `head(dput(olympicData))` and copy/paste the console output in your question.

Comment: You should share the data structure and the error message to let us know what is going on... For example, I do not know if that "`" character at the end of the code is not just typo when you typed the code here... From the information you provided, that could be considered one cause...

Answer (score 0):

### Assuming you are working with the data frame df

```
df 

#Load package
 library(tidyverse) # Helpful while using pipeline 
 
#we need to group the data with year and sex variables and then summarise the data
 df %>% group_by(Year,Sex) %>% summarise(count=n())
```

Comment: OP has asked for proportions, not counts.